# MySQL Ignoring Specific Rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a SQL query to obtain results with the column applicationstatus that aren't S to tell which position is still open. There are 3 application status U=Unsuccessful, O = ongoing and S =  successful. This works fine. Below is the code I am running.

```
SELECT DISTINCT position.position_ID, Title, EmployerName, Industry
FROM position
JOIN application ON position.position_id = application.position_id
JOIN employer ON position.employer_id = employer.employer_id
WHERE applicationstatus != 'S'
```

The problem I am facing is with the above query code, let's assume position_ID 3212 has received 3 applications, with one successful application; I get 2 results for the mentioned position(Excluding the successful one) like this.

[image]

Is there a way to filter it so that if a position already has a successful application, then the rows with the same position ID will be ignored?

Comment: Your query will ignore such duplicates, because it not contains column `applicationstatus` in `SELECT`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't, I just included applicationstatus afterwards to make it easier to read. PositionID 3212 still shows even without the applicationstatus. Felix's advice of using Exist worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `NOT EXISTS` condition to exclude `position`s with successful applications:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.position_ID,
    Title,
    EmployerName,
    Industry
FROM position p
JOIN application a
    ON p.position_id = a.position_id
JOIN employer e
    ON p.employer_id = e.employer_id
WHERE
    applicationstatus != 'S'
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM application
        WHERE
            position_id = a.position_id
            AND applicationstatus = 'S'
    )
```

Note that I've rewritten your query to use meaningful aliases. You should also do this to improve readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: That was very fast! It works too! Many thanks Felix! I wasn't aware of the Exist condition, thank you Felix! Will also start using the aliases as you stated, thanks again!

Comment: @ilovetaufu Glad I could help. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.